# Wordpress - Site with different content for each user

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress website where users, after paying and becoming member, will have access to private contents. These contents have to be different for each user: when a user become member, I need to generate a individual schedule based on data entered by the user. When a user access to his personal page, he needs to see his personal schedule. For the part of membership I found my usefull plugins but for showing personal content I haven't found anything that can help me.
How can I achieve it? Is there any plugin that can fit my needs? If I need to entirely code it, how can I do for inserting this feature in classic multi-purpose wordpress theme?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you create new role "member" for users. You can check this when they visit your page with this code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'member', $user->roles ) ) {
    //Your code if user is "member"
}
```

`wp_get_current_user();` returned `WP_User` object. For more details see [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/)

Comment: The fact is that I don't need a content equal to all members but it has to be different for each user. The thing might something like I do a query with the id of the user that returns me the content of this specific user that I have generated before.

Comment: @rubipop Inside returned object you have - the user’s ID. Check it like `user->ID`. Read my link above to the documentation.